# my ajax throwing 404 error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written an AJAX call which works fine but after successfully running firebug, shows the error: http://localhost:8000/js/main.js Moved permanantly and 404. But Why is it searching for a js file when the call returns successful.

My Ajax:

```
$.ajax({

        type:'POST',

        url:"/foobar/",

        data:{"foo": bar},

        success:function(data) {

            $('#wrapper').html(data);

        }

        });
```

**First Response:**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Mailserved</title>
<link href="css/new-master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.editinplace.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head
<body>
// Here body .......
</body>
```

**Second Response**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Page not found at /foobar/js/main.js/</title>
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    table { border:none; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; }
    td, th { vertical-align:top; padding:2px 3px; }
    th { width:12em; text-align:right; color:#666; padding-right:.5em; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ol { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info ol li { font-family: monospace; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="summary">
    <h1>Page not found <span>(404)</span></h1>
    <table class="meta">
      <tr>
        <th>Request Method:</th>
        <td>GET</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Request URL:</th>
      <td>http://localhost:8000/foobar/send/js/main.js/</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="info">

      <p></p>

  </div>

  <div id="explanation">
    <p>
      You're seeing this error because you have <code>DEBUG = True</code> in
      your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>, and Django
      will display a standard 404 page.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

    </html>
```

**observation:**

```
<th>Request URL:</th>
          <td>http://localhost:8000/foobar/send/js/main.js/</td>
```

This might cause problem Why this is coming and how to resolve

Comment: does the call complete successfully? Does the URL you are calling exist?

Comment: The script missing could be completely separate from the ajax call. Are you positive there is nothing else trying to call that script? If you do not do the ajax call (comment it out) and load the page, do you still get the 404?

Comment: Random guess: You have your ajax code written in this `main.js` file and you get error 404 because it's trying to look for a missing page from `http://localhost:8000/foobar/`, and the error is from `main.js` so the error code is appearing as `404 .... Moved permanently`? Take note that your url is starting with `/`

Comment: Are you sure it is a 301 Moved Permanently (not 302 Object Moved) followed by 404 Not Found? In any case, in Firebug, expand the first response (the 301/302) and second response (the 404) copy-paste the response headers in your question.

Answer (score 0):

your directory index is missing mate.

check inside your /foobar/ for index.html etc (or whatever directory index yo have)

PS: Move Permanently is not a 4004 error. 404 is File Not found

Comment: @thank but i mean that first it tell me that File moved permanantly than next line told me file not found